# Is it really necessary to have at least 60 minutes for a train connection?

Tags: transit, trains, norway, short-connections

I'm trying to book a train from Trondheim via Oslo to Kristiansand. The route contains a  transfer in Oslo. I have 21 minutes to catch the connection.
On the NSB site [a warning is issued (Google Translate link)](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nsb.no%2Ftogbilletter%2Freisebetingelser-og-vilkar%2Fovergangsregler&edit-text=&act=url) that when the route contains a transfer a gap of at least 60 minutes should be planned, otherwise there is no refund possible in case of a missed connection.

Is this warning based on reality (i.e. do long distance trains often have delays) or is it just to protect the NSB and minimise the amount of refunds?

Or in my specific case: should I be concerned about the 21 minute transfer time and book another train?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have traveled in Norway on the train network and found it to be exceptionally punctual. 
However, the journey time from Trondheim to Oslo is around 7 hours, and you only need one small problem to crop up to end up having to pay for a extra segment to Kristiensand.
The NSB website shows that it is a possible connection, but flags a warning.

Looking at the online time table it seems that you are hoping to catch the 23.13 in Trondheim, for the overnight service, with the connection at 07.25. My suggestion would to be on the safe side and aim for the connection at 11.01. That would give you a few hours in Oslo to get breakfast.

The standard price of the Oslo Kristiensand journey is 677kr, which is a lot to pay for if you miss the connection.
Even though I think it is likely that you could make the earlier train, my personal thought is don't risk it.

Comment: does "punctual" also include early arrival of trains... or is it typically just in time?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on @tor-elinar's answer, but if you book a Minipris ticket it is my understanding that you must travel on the trains you have reservations for  the website says 'Minipris: (Lowest Price)
Must be purchased at least 1 day prior to departure and can not be purchased on board the trains. Tickets are non-refundable, also in combination with Sove and Komfort, and reservations may not be changed.'

Comment: @SunWKim in my personal experience it is on time, and not usually early.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if you have read the Google translation you are linking to, because you're misquoting it.

First of all, the minimum suggested transfer time between regional trains on the Trondheim - Oslo - Kristiansand lines (as in your case) is 60 minutes. The 30 minutes you refer to is the suggested transfer time between "other trains". The text does not mention anything about a refund in case of a lost connection but reimbursement of additional expenses:

> For journeys where shorter transition time is chosen it can not be
>   claimed for reimbursement of expenses for alternative transportation
>   or other expenses incurred as a result of lost connection.

Basically, if you reach your destination with more than 60 minutes delay, NSB is liable to reimburse you with 50% of the ticket price and under some circumstances even additional expenses to cover alternative means of transport, meals or lodging. Since long distance trains operate relatively infrequently in Norway, a short delay on the first leg can easily cause you a significant delay at the final destination if you have a transfer. Even if trains often wait for corresponding passengers in Norway, a 20 minute delay on your first leg from Trondheim to Oslo could in theory be enough to miss the connection, causing a 4 hour delay in Kristiansand if you had to wait for the next train. The disclaimer in the journey planner is just to inform you that you waive your rights to these reimbursments in case of a missed connection, so that you cannot hold NSB liable for providing alternative transport, meals or to cover other expenses you've had related to the delay.

However, if you *should* miss the connection in Oslo, NSB will allow you to proceeed the journey on the next possible train.

Comment: `However, if you should miss the connection ... on the next possible train. ` My understanding is that this only holds when you have a regular ticket, right? A Minipris ticket only allows you to take the trains you booked in advance (as Martin Jevon points out).

Comment: If NSB sells you a through ticket, I would be highly surprised if the rest of the ticket is void if you miss a connection because of a delayed train. The situation is neither mentioned in the conditions for the minipris tickets, nor in the general transport conditions. I'll see if I can find more. You should however edit your question to match reality. As I pointed out, you are misquoting most of the disclaimer.

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in chat...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16032/is-it-really-necessary-to-have-at-least-30-minutes-for-a-train-connection)

Comment: Hi. Tor-einar.  NSB regulations specify that you should allow 30/60 mins. You could choose to take the risk and choose the 21 min connection, but NSB having informed you of the risk would have no obligation to give you space on the next train if you have only paid the Minipris ticket.  This is also the case in the uk, where if you purchace an 'advance' ticket you must travel on the specified train.

Comment: I finally got an answer from NSB customer service yesterday. If you miss a connection and haven't kept the required transfer time, the rest of your minipris ticket is actually void. This is *not* the case in the UK. If you miss a connection with an advance ticket, you can use the next possible train, as per the terms and conditions "If delays occur while travelling, you will be allowed to take the next available train(s) to complete your journey." I find it extremely odd that NSB is allowed to sell through tickets with short connection stimes and leave you stranded if a connection is misssed.